# Combo Box in ActivityDesigner loses it's selection when the control is closed

Tags: data-binding, combobox, workflow-foundation, selecteditem, activitydesigner

first time posting here.. so go easy =)

I am trying to learn the Workflow model, and ended up creating my own activity. Below is the XAML for the combo box in question.

`<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PossibleValues}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ModelItem.SelectedEvent, Converter={StaticResource LifeEventConverter}}"`

I have the following property defined in my Code Activity:

```
Public Property SelectedEvent As LifeEvents
```

The code works, my problem is whenever I close and reopen visual studio the combo box does not keep the last selected item. The property does keep it's value, but it driving me nuts that I can't tell what item is selected just looking at my workflow.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell for sure what the problem is but for a start the normal way to define input arguments to an activity it by creating properties of type InArgument. Not sure if that will solve your problem though.

The first thing I would check is if selected value, or anything else, shows up in the XAML for SelectedEvent.

Comment: Hi Maurice. Thanks for the answer. Not sure how to check in the XAML for the selected event. I found a workaround by also binding the selected index in the XAML and creating an additional property on my class that binds to the "SelectedIndex". Pretty sure this wasn't the best way to do this.